# Replacing NULL with 0 in a SQL server query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have developed a query, and in the results for the first three columns I get `NULL`.  How can I replace it with `0`?

```
Select c.rundate, 
  sum(case when c.runstatus = 'Succeeded' then 1 end) as Succeeded, 
  sum(case when c.runstatus = 'Failed' then 1 end) as Failed, 
  sum(case when c.runstatus = 'Cancelled' then 1 end) as Cancelled, 
  count(*) as Totalrun from
  (    Select a.name,case when b.run_status=0 Then 'Failed' when b.run_status=1 Then 'Succeeded'
  when b.run_status=2 Then 'Retry' Else 'Cancelled' End as Runstatus,
  ---cast(run_date as datetime)
              cast(substring(convert(varchar(8),run_date),1,4)+'/'+substring(convert(varchar(8),run_date),5,2)+'/'          +substring(convert(varchar(8),run_date),7,2) as Datetime) as RunDate
  from msdb.dbo.sysjobs as a(nolock) inner join msdb.dbo.sysjobhistory as b(nolock) 
  on a.job_id=b.job_id
  where a.name='AI'
  and b.step_id=0) as c
  group by 
  c.rundate
```

Comment: @user2246674 The first three columns: sum(case when c.runstatus = 'Succeeded' then 1 end) as Succeeded, sum(case when c.runstatus = 'Failed' then 1 end) as Failed, sum(case when c.runstatus = 'Cancelled' then 1 end) as Cancelled

Comment: Sparky, Oracle is different not isnull to use NVL or NVL2 ... check https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/null-related-functions

Answer (score 524, accepted):

When you want to replace a possibly `null` column with something else, use [IsNull](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325.aspx).

```
SELECT ISNULL(myColumn, 0 ) FROM myTable
```

This will put a 0 in myColumn if it is null in the first place.

Comment: For those few using SQL Server 2000 or 2005 ISNULL is SQL Server 2008 and above.

Comment: for multiple columns do I have to write ISNULL multiple times or is there something like ISNULL(myColumns, 0)?

Comment: @Kyle: That is incorrect: From personal experience (and [a book quote](https://books.google.at/books?id=7nYs9j2ddfUC&q=sql+server+2000+isnull&dq=sql+server+2000+isnull&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj03KulqMHaAhWMAsAKHdkiBWQQ6AEILTAB)), I can confirm that ISNULL is supported since (at least) SQL Server 2000, probably even earlier.

Comment: @Flaudre: You have to write ISNULL multiple times, since every output column must have its own expression.

Comment: This help me as well to get the accurate result in SQL Server 2016. Thanks a lot, you just made my day @phadaphunk

Comment: SQLite equivalent function is IFNULL()

Answer (score 114):

You can use both of these methods but there are differences:

```
SELECT ISNULL(col1, 0 ) FROM table1
SELECT COALESCE(col1, 0 ) FROM table1
```

**Comparing COALESCE() and ISNULL():**

1. The ISNULL function and the COALESCE expression have a similar
   purpose but can behave differently.
2. Because ISNULL is a function, it is evaluated only once. As
   described above, the input values for the COALESCE expression can be
   evaluated multiple times.
3. Data type determination of the resulting expression is different.
   ISNULL uses the data type of the first parameter, COALESCE follows
   the CASE expression rules and returns the data type of value with
   the highest precedence.
4. The NULLability of the result expression is different for ISNULL and
   COALESCE. The ISNULL return value is always considered NOT NULLable
   (assuming the return value is a non-nullable one) whereas COALESCE
   with non-null parameters is considered to be NULL. So the
   expressions ISNULL(NULL, 1) and COALESCE(NULL, 1) although
   equivalent have different nullability values. This makes a
   difference if you are using these expressions in computed columns,
   creating key constraints or making the return value of a scalar UDF
   deterministic so that it can be indexed as shown in the following
   example.

-- This statement fails because the PRIMARY KEY cannot accept NULL values
-- and the nullability of the COALESCE expression for col2 
-- evaluates to NULL.

```
CREATE TABLE #Demo 
( 
    col1 integer NULL, 
    col2 AS COALESCE(col1, 0) PRIMARY KEY, 
    col3 AS ISNULL(col1, 0) 
);
```

-- This statement succeeds because the nullability of the 
-- ISNULL function evaluates AS NOT NULL.

```
CREATE TABLE #Demo 
( 
    col1 integer NULL, 
    col2 AS COALESCE(col1, 0), 
    col3 AS ISNULL(col1, 0) PRIMARY KEY 
);
```

5. Validations for ISNULL and COALESCE are also different. For example,
   a NULL value for ISNULL is converted to int whereas for COALESCE,
   you must provide a data type.
6. ISNULL takes only 2 parameters whereas COALESCE takes a variable
   number of parameters.

   if you need to know more [here is the full document](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx) from msdn.

Answer (score 32):

With `coalesce`:

```
coalesce(column_name,0)
```

Although, where summing `when condition then 1`, you could just as easily change `sum` to `count` - eg:

```
count(case when c.runstatus = 'Succeeded' then 1 end) as Succeeded,
```

(`Count(null)` returns 0, while `sum(null)` returns null.)

Answer (score 14):

***A Simple way is***

```
UPDATE tbl_name SET fild_name = value WHERE fild_name IS NULL
```

Answer (score 14):

If you are using Presto, AWS Athena etc, there is no ISNULL() function. Instead, use:

```
SELECT COALESCE(myColumn, 0 ) FROM myTable
```

Answer (score 13):

When you say the first three columns, do you mean your `SUM` columns?  If so, add `ELSE 0` to your `CASE` statements.  The `SUM` of a `NULL` value is `NULL`.

```
sum(case when c.runstatus = 'Succeeded' then 1 else 0 end) as Succeeded, 
sum(case when c.runstatus = 'Failed' then 1 else 0 end) as Failed, 
sum(case when c.runstatus = 'Cancelled' then 1 else 0 end) as Cancelled,
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/31510/1)

Answer (score 8):

Wrap your column in this code.

```
ISNULL(Yourcolumn, 0)
```

Maybe check why you are getting nulls

Answer (score 7):

Use `COALESCE`, which returns the first not-null value e.g.

```
SELECT COALESCE(sum(case when c.runstatus = 'Succeeded' then 1 end), 0) as Succeeded
```

Will set Succeeded as 0 if it is returned as `NULL`.

Answer (score 1):

Add an else to your case statements so that they default to zero if the test condition is not found. At the moment if the test condition isn't found NULL is being passed to the SUM() function.

```
Select c.rundate, 
  sum(case when c.runstatus = 'Succeeded' then 1 else 0 end) as Succeeded, 
  sum(case when c.runstatus = 'Failed' then 1 else 0 end) as Failed, 
  sum(case when c.runstatus = 'Cancelled' then 1 else 0 end) as Cancelled, 
  count(*) as Totalrun from
  (    Select a.name,case when b.run_status=0 Then 'Failed' when b.run_status=1 Then 'Succeeded'
  when b.run_status=2 Then 'Retry' Else 'Cancelled' End as Runstatus,
  ---cast(run_date as datetime)
              cast(substring(convert(varchar(8),run_date),1,4)+'/'+substring(convert(varchar(8),run_date),5,2)+'/'          +substring(convert(varchar(8),run_date),7,2) as Datetime) as RunDate
  from msdb.dbo.sysjobs as a(nolock) inner join msdb.dbo.sysjobhistory as b(nolock) 
  on a.job_id=b.job_id
  where a.name='AI'
  and b.step_id=0) as c
  group by 
  c.rundate
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sum(case when c.runstatus = 'Succeeded' then 1 else 0 end) as Succeeded, 
sum(case when c.runstatus = 'Failed' then 1 else 0 end) as Failed, 
sum(case when c.runstatus = 'Cancelled' then 1 else 0 end) as Cancelled,
```

the issue here is that without the else statement, you are bound to receive a Null when the run status isn't the stated status in the column description.  Adding anything to Null will result in Null, and that is the issue with this query.

Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

by following previous answers I was losing my column name in SQL server db however following this syntax helped me to retain the ColumnName as well

```
ISNULL(MyColumnName, 0) MyColumnName
```

Answer (score 0):

For regular SQL, `ISNULL(item)` can only take one parameter, and thus 90% of these solutions don't work.

I repurposed @Krishna Chavali's answer to make this:

```
(CASE WHEN (NOT ISNULL(column_name)) THEN column_name ELSE 0 END) AS ColumnName
```

This will return the value in `column_name` if it is not `null`, and `0` if it is `null`.

Answer (score -5):

```
UPDATE TableName SET ColumnName= ISNULL(ColumnName, 0 ) WHERE Id = 10
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.