# Replace nulls values in sql using select statement?-change NULL to 'No commission'

Tags: sql, oracle

[image: Here is a screenshot]

I need to remove the Null in the commission column and change it to 'No commission'. Not sure how to write that code. I tried to use UPDATE or SET code but got errors.

This is the code I got so far.

```
SELECT First_Name || ' ' || Last_Name AS "Full Name", ' NZD' || ' ' || SALARY AS "Salary", 
COMMISSION_PCT AS "COMMISSION_%",SALARY * COMMISSION_PCT AS "Commission"
FROM EMPLOYEES
ORDER BY LAST_NAME desc;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replacing NULL with 0 in a SQL server query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16840522/replacing-null-with-0-in-a-sql-server-query)

Comment: I saw that post and try to do it using that code but keep getting error.

Answer (score 1):

Try using coalesce() or NVL() for oracle instead of ISNULL()

```
SELECT ISNULL(COMMISSION_PCT, 'No commission')
FROM EMPLOYEES
```

Comment: I've changed my code like SELECT  ISNULL (COMMISSION_PCT, "No commission"),
First_Name || ' ' || Last_Name AS "Full Name", ' NZD' || ' ' || SALARY AS "Salary", 
COMMISSION_PCT AS "COMMISSION_%",SALARY * COMMISSION_PCT AS "Commission"
FROM EMPLOYEES
ORDER BY LAST_NAME desc; but I am still getting error.

Comment: ORA-00904: "ISNULL": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 18 Column: 9

Comment: try coalesce() or NVL()  instead of isnull

Comment: @H.Cho Not the cause of this specific error message, but please note `"` and `'` are not interchangeable.

Answer (score 1):

For Oracle use:

```
NVL(pct_commission, 'No commission');
```

Comment: how do we use that code? Do I just add on to SELECT section?                     SELECT  First_Name || ' ' || Last_Name AS "Full Name", ' NZD' || ' ' || SALARY AS "Salary", 
COMMISSION_PCT AS "COMMISSION_%",SALARY * COMMISSION_PCT AS "Commission", NVL(pct_commission, 'No commission')
FROM EMPLOYEES
ORDER BY LAST_NAME desc; like this?

Comment: Try this: SELECT First_Name || ' ' || Last_Name AS "Full Name", ' NZD' || ' ' || SALARY AS "Salary",  NVL(COMMISSION_PCT, 'No commission') AS "COMMISSION_%",SALARY * NVL(COMMISSION_PCT, 0) AS "Commission" FROM EMPLOYEES ORDER BY LAST_NAME desc;

Comment: Well, yeah.  Ideally, you would replace null with 0 instead of "No commision" so the types would match up.  Will probably need to use to_char() to convert everything to a string: SELECT First_Name || ' ' || Last_Name AS "Full Name", ' NZD' || ' ' || SALARY AS "Salary", COMMISSION_PCT, AS "COMMISSION_%",SALARY * NVL(TO_CHAR(COMMISSION_PCT), 0) AS "Commission" FROM EMPLOYEES ORDER BY LAST_NAME desc;

Answer (score 1):

All values in a single column of a result must be of the same data type. If you want to show "No commission" instead, that means you also need to convert the number into a string. In Oracle this is done using the `to_char()` function.

```
SELECT First_Name || ' ' || Last_Name AS "Full Name", 
       ' NZD' || ' ' || SALARY AS "Salary", 
       COMMISSION_PCT AS "COMMISSION_%",
       nvl(to_char(salary * commission_pct, 'FM9999.99'), 'No Commission') AS "Commission"
FROM EMPLOYEES
ORDER BY LAST_NAME desc;
```