# mySQL - how to keep count() function from dropping 0 counts?

Tags: mysql, sql-merge

I'm new to mySQL and working on a query which essentially takes one initial table and summarizes its contents in two separate tables.  The second "summary" table is dropping tuples where a value is 0; I need to fix that.  Here's the specifics:

I have a large Inventory table, which I assemble from other tables:

```
SID  CID   SECTION  RATING
==========================
100  1001  1        A
101  1001  1        A
102  1002  1        B
103  1002  2        F
104  1003  1        A
...etc...
```

("CID" and "Section" are the primary keys here, I don't know if whether the PK is spread across two attributes is significant here.)  I have a successful query ("numTable1") which counts the number of SIDs for each CID and Section.  For example, with the above Inventory table, "sumTable1" would be:

```
CID   SECTION  numSID
=====================
1001  1        2
1002  1        1
1002  2        1
1003  1        1
...etc...
```

Here's the SQL:

```
create temporary table numTable1(
    SELECT ot1.cid, ot2.section, count(ot1.sid) 'numSID'
    FROM otherTable1 ot1, otherTable2 ot2
    WHERE ot1.cid=ot2.cid and ot1.section=ot2.section
    GROUP BY ot1.cid, ot2.section
);
```

"NumTable" works great.  Here's the problem:  I also need a query which counts the number of 'A' Ratings per CID/Section:

```
create temporary table numA(
    select t9.cid, t9.section, count(ot1.rating) 'As'
    from otherTable1 ot1, t9
    where grade = 'A' and t9.cid=ot1.cid and t9.section=ot1.section
    group by t9.cid, t9.section
```

);

Here's the output of "numA":

```
CID   SECTION  As
=====================
1001  1        2
1003  1        1
...etc...
```

But here's the problem; some CID/Sections have no A Ratings, and they are being washed out.  What I need is this:

```
CID   SECTION  As
=====================
1001  1        2
1002  1        0
1002  2        0
1003  1        1
...etc...
```

You'll note that the above table can be seamlessly merged with "numTable1", which is the ultimate aim here:

```
CID   SECTION  numSID   As
==========================
1001  1        2        2
1002  1        1        0
1002  2        1        0
1003  1        1        1
```

But as long as "numA" drops CID/Sections with 0 As, I'm dead in the water.  I assume my "group by" statement in "numA" is washing out the zeroes... but I'm not sure about that.  Any suggestions?

Comment: is not clear to me  you want remove the rows with as =  0 form the last table ?

Comment: You have to join back your counts to the base data to enrich it with the 0 count records.

Comment: Look into LEFT JOINs for your queries

Comment: @scaisEdge thanks for the clarification...  No, I need the rows with 0s.  The problem with the "numA" query is that it is dropping the 0 rows... I need to fix that.

Comment: @NigelRen -- Thanks, that's a great idea.  When I do the left join, I get the "0 rows" that were being dropped, but the values of "Aa" is NULL, not 0.  Is there some syntax tweak which can swap NULLs for 0s?

Comment: @NigelRen - oh wait:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16840522/replacing-null-with-0-in-a-sql-server-query#16840585  Duh...!

Answer (score 0):

@NigelRen provided the solution - a left join.  Here's the code:

```
-- Left Join on numTable1 with numA... makes for total students // numAs
-- Resultant table is totA: "Total A Ratings"
create temporary table totA(
    select numTable1.cid, numTable19.section, numTable1.numStudents, if(numA.As is null, 0, numA.As) 'A Ratings'
    from numTable1
    left join numA on numTable1.cid=numA.cid and numTable1.section=numA.section
);
```