# Rename category in the column in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

Here is the query

```
select col1
from table
```

`col1` contains these category values:

```
A
B
C
NULL
```

How can I rename `null` category to `D`?

Comment: ANSI SQL solution is `coalesce(col1, 'D')`, works for SQL Server and basically any other dbms!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replacing NULL with 0 in a SQL server query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16840522/replacing-null-with-0-in-a-sql-server-query)

Comment: What happens if there are 2 NULLs in col1?

Comment: nothing but i have hundreds null

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to make the change permanent

```
UPDATE table
SET col1 = 'D'
WHERE col1 IS NULL
```

From then on you can simply query with ...

```
SELECT col1
FROM table
```

... to get the desired result.

---

If there is more than one row having a `NULL` in `col1`, you need to filter by a unique key, preferably by the primary key (which every table should have by the way). Let's say you have a table like

```
id (PK)   col1
---       ----
1         'A'
2         'B'
3         'C'
4         NULL
5         NULL
```

then you can fix it with

```
UPDATE table SET col1 = 'D' WHERE id = 4;
UPDATE table SET col1 = 'E' WHERE id = 5;
```

unless you can calculate the new value from another column, e.g.:

```
UPDATE table 
SET col1 = UPPER(LEFT(name, 1))
```

Comment: Thank  you. Good solution.

Answer (score 2):

Try this : ISNULL( ) function is used to replace NULL value with another value

```
select isnull(col1,'D') as col1
from table
```

Answer (score 2):

SQL Server uses [ISNULL()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/isnull-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017%20).

```
SELECT ISNULL(value_to_check, use_this_instead_if_valuetocheck_is_null)
```

For your code:

```
select ISNULL(col1, 'D') AS col_name
from table
```

However, this will happen across the board for this column. You can't use this to make a sequence, like D then E then F. Any NULL value you come across in this column will change to D.