# How to use a case statement in a SQL query?

Tags: sql

How to replace NULL value of specific column with other column value. For example: If second name of customer is not given then add father name in second name column.

Comment: Which SQL database do you use?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replacing NULL with 0 in a SQL server query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16840522/replacing-null-with-0-in-a-sql-server-query)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with case statement as below-

```
SELECT
CASE 
    WHEN second_name IS NULL OR second_name = '' THEN father_name 
    ELSE second_name
END AS second_name
FROM your_table
```

Comment: thanks now there is one more condition of middle name null

Comment: No matter what can be done, its all depends on what you wants? Just explain your requirement. There is always a solution. :)

Answer (score 1):

use `coalesce()`

```
select coalesce(secondname ,fathername) from tablename
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [COALESE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_(SQL)#COALESCE)

```
SELECT COALESE(second_name, first_name) from mytable;
```

AFAIK, it is supported on Oracle, MS SQL Server, MySQL and Postgres.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ifnull function as well. The syntax should be like :

```
select ifnull(second_name,father_name) from user;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COALESCE(NULLIF(second_name, ''), father_name) from table
```

You can handle blank and NULL values in the second_name column and if these values are there it will show value from father_name column