# How to eleiminate NULL with 0 in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a simple table now I want when I run sql statement it should replace `NULL` with 0 using mysql

Here is what I have tried so far

```
SELECT IFNULL(targetbuttonname, 0), sessions.sid, events.datetime, count(*) as num_rows,
  count(distinct sessions.sid) as sessions, 
  sum( targetbuttonname = 'kredyt' ) as num_kredyt, 
  sum(devicetype ='Computer') as num_computer from events
```

Now when I run my script it still returns null

Here is DEMO [demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3cf3cf/3)

What is wrong with my query statement?

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: @Strawberry I updated with demo link thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replacing NULL with 0 in a SQL server query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16840522/replacing-null-with-0-in-a-sql-server-query)

Comment: @user9964622 Its `IFNULL` your link has `ISNULL`

Comment: @PrashantDeshmukh..... i am trying different methods

Comment: @Tayyab ifyou think is duplicate the please correct my error via demo , I will apreciate

Comment: Your query is invalid SQL. What are you trying to select? One row with all the sums and counts? Or one row per session? Or one row per date? Or one row per session and date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `COALESCE`

```
SELECT coalesce(NULL,0), sessions.sid, events.datetime, count(*) as num_rows, count(distinct sessions.sid) as sessions, 
  sum( targetbuttonname = 'kredyt' ) as num_kredyt, 
  sum( targetbuttonname = 'konto' ) as num_konto,
  sum( targetbuttonname = 'czat' ) as num_czat,
  sum( targetbuttonname = 'video-voice_btns' ) as num_voice,
  sum( targetbuttonname = 'video-close_btn' )  as num_close,
  sum( targetbuttonname = 'video-muted_btn' ) as num_muted,
  sum( targetbuttonname = 'video-play_btn' )  as num_play,
  sum( targetbuttonname = 'video-pause_btn' )  as num_pause,
  sum( targetbuttonname = 'video-replay_btn' ) as num_replay, 
  sum(watchtime) as num_watchtime, 
  sum(devicetype ='Computer') as num_computer from events  INNER JOIN sessions ON (events.sid =sessions.sid) WHERE events.datetime BETWEEN '2019-11-11' AND '2019-11-21'
```

DEMO: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3cf3cf/10

`IFNULL` will also work:

```
SELECT ifnull(targetbuttonname,0), sessions.sid, events.datetime, count(*) as num_rows, count(distinct sessions.sid) as sessions, 
  sum( targetbuttonname = 'kredyt' ) as num_kredyt, 
  sum( targetbuttonname = 'konto' ) as num_konto,
  sum( targetbuttonname = 'czat' ) as num_czat,
  sum( targetbuttonname = 'video-voice_btns' ) as num_voice,
  sum( targetbuttonname = 'video-close_btn' )  as num_close,
  sum( targetbuttonname = 'video-muted_btn' ) as num_muted,
  sum( targetbuttonname = 'video-play_btn' )  as num_play,
  sum( targetbuttonname = 'video-pause_btn' )  as num_pause,
  sum( targetbuttonname = 'video-replay_btn' ) as num_replay, 
  sum(watchtime) as num_watchtime, 
  sum(devicetype ='Computer') as num_computer from events  INNER JOIN sessions ON (events.sid =sessions.sid) WHERE events.datetime BETWEEN '2019-11-11' AND '2019-11-21'
```

Here is the DEMO: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3cf3cf/14

Comment: Thanks for help , now when I change the date range to dates which are not in the table still return NAN, ,meaning null

Comment: meaning on console it shows null and on browser it shows NAN

Comment: just change the range of the dates  like this WHERE events.datetime BETWEEN '2019-04-11' AND '2019-03-21'

Comment: Ok, but then you have to do coalesce for every column!

Comment: So, this is what you want: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/332ef1/7 ??

Comment: I am checking brb