# how to replace blank & NULL in SELECT

Tags: sql, sql-server

Please let me question about how to replace blank & NULL value in SELECT.
I have a column that is defined by VARCHAR like below. It has blank and NULL values in some row. How can I replace both blank and NULL in SELECT?

[Replacing NULL with 0 in a SQL server query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16840522/replacing-null-with-0-in-a-sql-server-query)
-> This thread answered replacing only NULL

```
col1
------------
abc
------------
def
------------
NULL         <<<<<<<<<< NULL
------------
ghi
------------
             <<<<<<<<<< Blank
------------
jkl
```

Comment: Please tag DB engine that you use

Answer (score 3):

You can use a `case` expression or `nullif()`.  Something like this:

```
select coalesce(nullif(col, ''), <replacement value>) as col
```

If the logic is more complicated -- say strings of blanks -- then `case` is simpler:

```
select (case when col is null or replace(col, ' ') = '' 
             then <replacement value>
             else col
        end) as col
```