# Fill Missing Datasets in SQL View

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have to fill missing data in a table for our BI Tool to represent the data correct.
I would like to create a view that fills the gaps with the missing data from other months in the year.

For a better understanding a simplified representation of my source table:

| YEAR | MONTH | REVENUE | COSTCENTER | CUSTOMER |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020 | 1 | 20563.21 | 1 | 2 |
| 2020 | 1 | 1563.21 | 1 | 3 |
| 2020 | 1 | 20673.21 | 3 | 2 |
| 2020 | 1 | 10.24 | 4 | 3 |
| 2020 | 2 | 20563.21 | 1 | 2 |
| 2020 | 2 | 1563.21 | 5 | 3 |
| 2020 | 2 | 20673.21 | 6 | 2 |
| 2020 | 2 | 10.24 | 7 | 3 |
| 2020 | 3 | 20563.21 | 1 | 2 |
| 2020 | 3 | 1563.21 | 2 | 2 |
| 2020 | 3 | 20673.21 | 6 | 3 |
| 2020 | 3 | 10.24 | 7 | 2 |

As you can see February is missing the revenue for the costcenter 1 and customer 3 and the revenue for the costcenter 3 for the customer 2.
The costcenters are also linked to a customer, so I would need to fill in every cost center for a customer for every month for which a customer already reported a revenue in the year.
The filled in datasets must have 0 revenue of course.

I hope this was more or less clear what I try to achieve.
I would be really glad for some help with this.

Comment: you need to tag this with the database you are using

Comment: You have one answer that demonstrates the principle (though with significant issues). You need a set of cost centers, customers and periods. You then cross join the three and then outer join to your table to get all possible sets. Surely these sets already exist in your database (or can be derived). An actual calendar table can greatly help with the periods (and querying by dates generally).

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you create a second table that lists all years and months you are looking at.

Then create another table that lists all your customers and another one that lists all your costcenters.

```
SELECT customer
INTO Customer_List
FROM your_table
GROUP BY customer



SELECT costcenter
INTO Costcenter_List
FROM your_table
GROUP BY costcenter
```

Next step is to [union](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/set-operators-union-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) the three tables - you get a table with four columns: Year, Month, Customer, Costcenter.

Then you can use [left join](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/joins?view=sql-server-ver15) to get all the data from your initial table into that one. Where there is no match SQL will write NULL (empty).

As a last step you can [replace all NULL values with 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16840522/replacing-null-with-0-in-a-sql-server-query/26924388).

Comment: Hm should be possible with a distinct select for each year per customer on the costcenter, will try it thanks so far.

Comment: I guess, not to "union" these three tables,but CROSS JOIN them to get all possible combinations of customer,costcenter, year and month

Comment: You can also do this in a single step but I find temporary tables are easier to build if the dataset is fairly small and you want to keep nested functions to a minimum. But most people here would disagree that this approach is nice - it works nonetheless.

Comment: Creating actual tables for this makes your code more fragile. Do you see the assumptions in this approach? Only one process can execute this logic at a time and somehow those permanent tables must be deleted before the next execution of this logic (or "reused").

Comment: DROP TABLE IF EXISTS would solve this but agreed - creating actual tables is not the "right" way of doing this, but it works.

Answer (score 1):

He's a slightly different approach via a `UNION ALL`.  The `CROSS JOIN`s will generate all combinations of Year,Month (1-12), CostCenter and Customer.

The UNION ALL generates more rows than necessary but may be faster than the JOINS.

**Example or [dbFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=aed25e0d9cc049384bf26c99a3b69023)**

```
with cteY  as ( Select Distinct Year from YourTable )
    ,cteM  as ( Select top 12 Month = row_number() over (order by (select null)) from YourTable)
    ,cteCC as ( Select Distinct CostCenter from YourTable)
    ,cteC  as ( Select Distinct Customer   from YourTable)

Select Year,Month,Revenue=0,CostCenter,Customer 
 From  cteY
 Cross Join cteM
 Cross Join cteCC
 Cross Join cteC
Union All
Select Year
      ,Month
      ,Revenue
      ,CostCenter
      ,Customer
 From  YourTable
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 WITH YOUR_TABLE(YEAR,MONTH,REVENUE,COSTCENTER,CUSTOMER)AS
 (
    SELECT 2020,    1 , 20563.21,   1 , 2 UNION ALL
    SELECT 2020 ,   1 , 1563.21 ,   1 , 3 UNION ALL
    SELECT 2020 ,   1 , 20673.21,   3 , 2 UNION ALL
    SELECT 2020 ,   1,  10.24,      4 , 3 UNION ALL
    SELECT 2020 ,   2 , 20563.21,   1 , 2 UNION ALL
    SELECT 2020 ,   2 , 1563.21 ,   5 , 3 UNION ALL
    SELECT 2020 ,   2 , 20673.21,   6 , 2 UNION ALL
    SELECT 2020 ,   2 , 10.24,      7,  3 UNION ALL
    SELECT 2020 ,   3 , 20563.21 ,  1 , 2 UNION ALL
    SELECT 2020,    3 , 1563.21 ,   2 , 2 UNION ALL
    SELECT 2020,    3 , 20673.21 ,  6 , 3 UNION ALL
    SELECT 2020 ,   3,  10.24,      7 , 2
 ),
UQ_YEARS AS
 (
   SELECT DISTINCT  YEAR AS YEAR FROM YOUR_TABLE
 ),
UQ_MONTHS AS
 (
    SELECT DISTINCT MONTH AS MONTH FROM YOUR_TABLE
 ),
UQ_COSTCENTER AS
 (
   SELECT DISTINCT COSTCENTER FROM YOUR_TABLE
 ),
UQ_CUSTOMER AS
(
  SELECT DISTINCT CUSTOMER FROM YOUR_TABLE
),
ALL_COMBINATIONS AS
(  
   SELECT Y.YEAR,M.MONTH,CENTER.COSTCENTER,CUSTOMER.CUSTOMER
   FROM UQ_YEARS AS Y
   CROSS JOIN UQ_MONTHS AS M
   CROSS JOIN UQ_COSTCENTER AS CENTER
   CROSS JOIN UQ_CUSTOMER AS CUSTOMER
 )
SELECT A.YEAR,A.MONTH, A.COSTCENTER,A.CUSTOMER,ISNULL(TT.REVENUE,0.00)AS REVENUE
FROM ALL_COMBINATIONS AS A
LEFT JOIN YOUR_TABLE AS TT ON A.MONTH=TT.MONTH AND A.YEAR=TT.YEAR
 AND A.COSTCENTER=TT.COSTCENTER AND A.CUSTOMER=TT.CUSTOMER
```

Comment: Are you aware of a function that would ensure all 12 months are in the dataset? For example, if no cost and no customer entry exists for June 2020, your query would omit June, wouldn't it?